# Count array with array_count_values

Tags: php, arrays

My PHP Script

```
    $file_carrito=file("carrito.dat");

    $x=0;

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($file_carrito);$i++)
    {
    $array_products_1[]=$file_carrito[$i];

    $x++;
    }



echo (array_count_values($array_products_1));
```

In this simple file .dat , store all products the user add , and count in each case total of products for each id and case

For example i can have into the file 5 ids for one product and other 4 for other product id , finally , this must count products with te same id stored into de dat file

For example : 5 pencils , 3 chairs , 2 tables , etc .....

```
The problem it´s no works : echo (array_count_values($array_productos_1)); 



content of carrito.dat :

p1
p1
p1
p3
p3
p3
p2
p2
p2
p1
p1



With this function of array i want get :

Product p1 ---- (5)
Product p2 ----- (3) , etc
```

Thank´s

Comment: You should show what `carrito.dat` looks like

Comment: What *does* it do? "Doesn't work" isn't a problem description.

Comment: Use sessions [local or server] better than relying on files.

Comment: I want file based server , in the file .dat each product use \n for separate and in the bucle i can recover these , before i create array and with this function i want count the products with the same id and get this value , thank´s regards

Comment: this works with print_r but with echo (array_count_values($array_productos_1));  , no works

Answer (score 0):

count your values like this

```
$array = array('x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y');
$counts = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    $counts[$value] = array_key_exists($value, $counts) ? $counts[$value]+1 : 1;
}

print_r($counts);
```

in your case. the array fill with

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents(...));
```

Comment: Yes but i need get normal values , no in this form , no use print_r ..... thank´s

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
$data = file('carrito.dat');

print_r(array_count_values($data));
```

It will show something like the below:

```
Array
(
    [p1] => 5
    [p3] => 3
    [p2] => 3
)
```

Comment: $data = file('carrito.dat');    $products = array_count_values($data);    foreach ($product as $key => $value) {    echo "Product $key ---- $value<br />";    }